# Socket, HTTP query or Long Polling for 5000 connected clients?

Tags: delphi, sockets, nginx, rabbitmq, long-polling

I've about 5000 Windows clients written in Delphi and residing in office LANs which needs to access new data updated to a "Cloud", basically PHP(IIS) + Replicated MySQL website hosted on 2 x Windows 2003 VPS machines with 1GB RAM (I can upgrade to 2GB).

End users can access via the Internet and data updated by these users needs to be used by these Windows client residing behind office firewalls.

*Note:* If you are asking why are the Clients behind the firewall - they contain critical company information.

Since the clients are located behind firewall, the clients must connect to the VPS directly to download data updates.

There are several different connection methods that I can think of:

**1). Sockets**: Run a socket server on the Windows VPS and have each of the 5000 clients connect to the socket server constantly.

*Pros*: No 3rd party codes.
*Cons*: Low level. Unknown scalability and stability for large number of clients connecting at the same time. Stuck to Windows platform for the time being unless I use Lazarus which is not stable yet.

**2). RabbitMQ**: Run RabbitMQ (or equivalent) on the VPS and then get each of the 5000 clients to connect to the RabbitMQ server via AMQP.  On the Windows VPS, create a Delphi application that connect to RabbitMQ to send data inserted by PHP into MySQL.

*Pros*: Send data and forget - no need to manage queue using MySQL.
*Cons*: Complexities in managing RabbitMQ and possible bugs (especially for replication) while only using simple queues.  Queues may use a lot of memory.

**3). HTTP Query**: Program the 5000 clients to send an HTTP GET to the VPS every 5 seconds or so. The HTTP server will return data if there are updates and send a "no data" response if there are none.

Firstly, IIS is definitely out - my existing IIS hangs even if 5 users is downloading files - IIS resets by itself after a couple minutes, not sure it's IIS or the VPS.

I may use Apache (or Nginx) + PHP or create a custom Delphi HTTP server if that improves performance. If I were to use PHP, I would create a flag file (or use Memcached?) for clients that unread data - this is to prevent excessive MySQL queries on the queue table. For custom Delphi HTTP server, I could query MySQL to load all changes (for all clients) into memory every 1 second.

*Pros*: Fool proof and easiest to implement and works with Apache/PHP so I can even switch to Linux in the future.  Easy to implement security using SSL.
*Cons*: Scalability issue - whether 5000 clients can query every 5 seconds without hanging the server.

**4). Long Polling?**  I'm not familiar with long polling. Similar to HTTP Query but with delayed response?

*Pros:* Would be promising if there's a web server that's built for long polling. 
*Cons:* Scalability unknown.

I've read dozens of articles comparing HTTP vs Socket vs Long polling, but I'm still unsure which method I should use given the very limited server resource that I'm using and limited manpower and technical expert.

Which would you use if you were me and why?

*Note*: I also just read about Memcached but it doesn't support replication on Windows.  Most highly scalable web platforms and servers are for Unixes so my options are limited on this respect.

Comment: While this is a nice question, I am afraid it is too broad here on SO.

Comment: I did further research on my own and according to this article - http://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html - it appears that HTTP queries can handle more users per GB memory than long polling

Comment: The downside is CPU usage but I guess it wouldn't be an issue since I only need to poll once every 5-10 seconds?  The next question is the maximum number of concurrent that HTTP servers can handle.